# Static member class cannot implement an interface

Tags: java

Can anyone explain why a static member class cannot implement an interface, unless the interface is a marker?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more info - show us a code snippet of what's not working.

Comment: I've also seen that on wikipedia: (CTRL+F it) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern . I don't agree with it.

Comment: Perhaps you're wondering why you can't create an interface that contains static methods?

Answer (score 4):

It can. For example, this compiles with no problems:

```
interface Foo {
    void foo();
}

class Outer {    
    static class Inner implements Foo {
        public void foo() {
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming `Inner` is what you mean by a "static member class" here? If not, please edit the question to provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes can implement any interface.

this link will clarifies your any doubt about inner class

http://www.oopweb.com/Java/Documents/ThinkingInJava/Volume/TIJ310.htm